# Azure IoT Edge: How to monitor the edge module (install) state for all devices on IoT hub

Tags: azure-iot-hub, azure-iot-edge

Is it possible to read events from IoT hubs in a way that we receive all status changes for IoT edge module installs? Possibly by receiving state changes to the edge agent reported properties of all connected devices?

Background: We are allowing users to "install" applications (represented by edge modules) on their edge devices on the fly through our own portal. We want to monitor changes to IoT devices and their modules, and note the changes in our database, so we can flag the corresponding apps as installed, removed, or failed.

Right now I can only find Event Grid based events for Device connected / disconnected events. I can also see that I can manually query the desired properties of each edge device's edge Agent separately. But since we will a large number of edge devices connected (>5000), polling them all just to see if something changed is not feasible.

Are the edge agent status changes of all IoT edge devices available as an event stream somewhere? Or is there a better solution?

Answer (score 0):

IoT Edge's integration with Azure Monitor may help ([docs](https://aka.ms/edgemon-docs)). It has a [module view](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/iot-edge/how-to-explore-curated-visualizations?view=iotedge-2020-11&tabs=devices%2Cmodules#iot-edge-device-details-workbook) that shows which modules are running and their availability. Since all the data is available in Log Analytics, you can create [custom visualizations](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/iot-edge/how-to-explore-curated-visualizations?view=iotedge-2020-11&tabs=devices%2Cmessaging#customize-workbooks) and processes using the data.

Answer (score 0):

The Module twins in Azure IoT Hub shall help in below based on the information stored with it.

- Monitoring the connectivity of the system
- Monitoring the health of IoT Edge deployments

The Azure IoT Edge runtime has "IoT Edge Agent" as one of two modules that performs installation / initiation of modules and updating / reporting of the status of the modules to the IoT Hub. The $edgeAgent maintains the health and connectivity data about both the IoT Edge agent and IoT Edge hub runtime modules.

The Azure IoT Edge hub runtime maintains the data about communications between the "IoT Edge hub" running on the device and that of Azure IoT hub via the $edgeHub.

High level Overview :

[image]

Here is "Azure Monitor workbooks for IoT" that provides views couple of views :

- An overview / state of active devices can be seen in the "Devices" View
- Alerts display as per rules configured for the devices in "Alerts" View

Azure Monitor workbooks can be tuned for seeing data at any level (device state, app status) of interest. The public templates can be modified to meet the need/requirement in hand. The data shall fetched based on resource-centric KQL queries on the InsightsMetrics table.

Screenshot of Devices View :
[image]

Screenshot of Alerts View:
[image]

References :

- [Monitor Module Twins](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-edge/how-to-monitor-module-twins?view=iotedge-2020-11)
- [Monitor Workbooks](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-edge/how-to-explore-curated-visualizations?view=iotedge-2020-11&tabs=devices%2Cmessaging#iot-edge-fleet-view-workbook)